# How to mark search results as read

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I just came back from vacation, and I have a few thousand messages to go through.  Is there a way for me to run a search in Outlook Web, and then say "mark all these results as read"?

If I click on the checkbox at the top (next to "All Folders"), it only selects the visible messages (about 15 at a time)

Comment: Why can't you select all and mark as read?

Answer (score -1):

The checkbox next to "All Folders" only selects items in view. As a workaround, you can select the first email, then hold Shift key and select the last email from the search result.

Update:

Enable the new Outlook web app via the "Try the new Outlook" toggle button.

[image]

Then, you can select all the search results via ticking the checkbox before Results.

[image]

Comment: Looks like I still have to select them a page at a time. (If I use the elevator to scroll to the bottom of the search results, and shift-click on the bottom one, nothing happens.)

Comment: @ChrisCurvey Notice that now. shift-click enables me to select only two dozen search results. Do you see the "Try the new Outlook" version at the top right corner? The new version enables you to select all emails from the search result.

Comment: Nope, I don't have the "try the new outlook" option.  Probably because this is a corporate outlook account.